# Finding zeros with ratios

Tags: equation-solving

I have a function that reads:

```
f[P_?NumericQ, 
Ob_?NumericQ] := -Sqrt[P/Ob^2 + Sqrt[P^2 + Ob^2 w^2]/Ob^2] Tan[
 Sqrt[-(P/Ob^2) + Sqrt[P^2 + Ob^2 w^2]/Ob^2]] + 
 Sqrt[-(P/Ob^2) + Sqrt[P^2 + Ob^2 w^2]/Ob^2]
 Tanh[Sqrt[P/Ob^2 + Sqrt[P^2 + Ob^2 w^2]/Ob^2]]
```

For each pair of numerical values of P and Ob, there are infinitely many solutions for w (denoted as w0, w1, w2, w3, ...).

I want to write a concise code that does the following:

1. Loops over values of Ob from 0 to 1.
2. For each value of Ob, finds a critical value of P (Pcr) that makes the ratio of w2/w1 approximately equal to 3 (with reasonable tolerance).
3. Stores or outputs these critical values of P for each Ob.
   I tried but couldn't come up with a successful one.
   Thanks for any help in advance.

Below is one of my trials:

```
     Remove["Global`*"];
     tolerance = 0.05;
     results = {};

     For[ObValue = 0.01, ObValue <= 1, ObValue += 0.01, 
    For[P = 0.01, P <= 1, P += 0.01,(*Add a loop for P values*)
    roots = NSolve[f[P, ObValue] == 0 && 0 < w < 20, w, Reals];
    If[Length[roots] > 1, w1 = w /. roots[[1]];
    w2 = w /. roots[[2]];
    Pcr = FindRoot[Abs[w2/w1 - 3] <= tolerance, {P, .1}];
    If[NumberQ[P /. Pcr], AppendTo[results, {ObValue, P /. Pcr}]; 
  Break[];] (*Exit P loop if critical value found*)];];];
```

results

Comment: What have you tried so far? Once you pinpoint a specific problem, we can more easily help you. Otherwise you are just for somebody to do your work for you.

Comment: Thanks @MarcoB, I just added one of my trials.

Comment: `P` is never assigned a numerical value in your loop, so `NSolve` cannot work with it. You should assign it a value just like you do with `ObValue`.

Comment: Thanks @MarcoB. I apologize for the error in my previous message. I've now corrected the code snippet. However, I'm encountering the same issue: the modified code isn't producing any output.

Comment: You really need to give some thought to what you are doing here. With the new modification, `Abs[w2/w1-3]` is just a number and does not depend on `P`, so you cannot "solve for P" any more. Your problem is quite complex, so you may want to break it down into smaller pieces, or try asking on the math forum for advice instead.

Answer (score 0):

With your function f[ ] as above, you can see the output of the function for a specific value. For example

```
f[0.1,0.2]
```

gives a formula with 2 terms, each with a square root and a tanh.

NSolve doesn't work on this

```
NSolve[f[0.1,0.2]==0,w]
```

it just sits there. So let's try FindRoot:

```
FindRoot[f[0.1, 0.2] == 0, {w, 1}]
```

this returns

```
{w -> 3.43538}
```

almost immediately. You can do this for many starting values of w in a number of ways. For example:

```
Table[FindRoot[f[0.1, 0.2] == 0, {w, w0}], {w0, 1, 50}]
```

spits out 50 different terms, some of them redundant (which you would likely want to remove). Then you can iterate over different values of P and Ob.

If you only want the value near 3.4, you can do:

```
FindRoot[f[0.1, 0.2] == 0, {w, Pi}]
```

To iterate this over Ob, you might do:

```
Table[FindRoot[f[0.1, Ob] == 0, {w, Pi}], {Ob, 0.1, 2, 0.1}]
```

which gives a variety of answers, one for each Ob value.

Comment: Thanks @bill for your great answer, Now I want the value of P that gives me the ratio of the second frequency to the first w2/w1 is close to 3. That is what I call Pcr.